# A boundary in $C^{0,1}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm currently learning PDE written by L.C Evans.
In the book there is this condition, for U bounded domain,
$$\partial U\;\text{is}\; C^1$$
But professor made a little change so that
$$\partial U\;\text{is }C^{0,1}$$
But I cannot find what is the meaning of the boundary of a domain is $C^{0,1}$.

Someone familiar what this is?

Comment: Continuous, piecewise $C^1$ maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, $C^{k,\alpha}$ means "$k$th order derivatives satisfy the Hölder condition of order $\alpha$". As a special case, $C^{0,1}$ means the [Lipschitz condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity). In the context of the boundary of a domain this means $U$ is a [Lipschitz domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_domain).